# DevBridge autocompletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

im trying to use DevBridge Autocomplete downloaded from https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

But i cant get it to work :(

I have a HTML input field looking like this:

```
<input type="text" name="city" size="12" value="City" id="autocomplete" autocomplete="off">
```

In the same file i got my JavaScript:

```
<script src="autocomplete/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="autocomplete/jquery.mockjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/cities.php',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
</script>
```

An example output of cities.php?autocomplete=aach looks like this:

```
{ "suggestions": [ { "value": "Aach ", "data": "Aach " },{ "value": "Aacha ", "data": "Aacha " },{ "value": "Aachen ", "data": "Aachen " } ] }
```

What am i missing?
Thx for help!

Comment: your HTML says `autocomplete="off"`, might that be the cause?

Comment: i think thats just to turn off the browsers autocomplete, so it doesnt handicap the jquery autocompletion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be the url issue , try instead of `cities.php?autocomplete=aach`
 the "cities.php?query=aach" request.
I think by default jquery-autocomplete sends `some_url?query=key_word`.

Comment: thx for your idea, but it still doesnt help. if i call cities.php?autocomplete=aach directly via my browser it works fine, but jquery autocomplete doesnt work. but at this point, i dont need this feature any more, but thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Devbridge documentation. It specify that if want to change the query string parameter name then you have to set the paramName option.

In your case set it as while initializing the autocomplete widget:

`paramName:"autocomplete"`

Line from Documentsation:

`paramName`: Default `query`. The name of the request parameter that contains the query.